# Keeping quotes from std out for passing to bash

Tags: python, bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli

Okay, this is a bit convoluted but I've got a python script that digests a json file and prints a string representation of that file like so

```
for id in pwds.keys():
    secret += f"\'{id}\' : \'{pwds[id]['username']},{pwds[id]['pswd']}\',"
secret = secret[:-1] + "}\'"

print(secret)
```

This is taken in by a jenkins pipeline so it can be passed to a bash script

```
def secret_string = sh (script: "python3 syncToSecrets.py", returnStdout: true)
sh label: 'SYNC', script: "bash sync.sh  ${ENVIRONMENT} ${secret_string}"
```

I can see that when python is printing the output it looks like

'{"key" : "value", "key" : "value"...}'
But when it gets to secret_string, and also the bash script it then looks like
{key : value, key : value}

This is how the bash script is calling it

```
ENV=$1; SECRET_STRING=$2;
aws secretsmanager create-secret --name NAME --secret-string "${SECRET_STRING}"
```

Which technically works, it just uploads the whole thing as a string instead of discrete KV-pairs.

I'm trying to run some stuff with the AWS CLI, and it requires that the data be wrapped in quotes, but so far, I've been totally unable to keep the quotes in between processes. Any advice?

Comment: Replace that first loop with `json.dump` - hand-formatting JSON never a good idea.

Comment: The *shell* requires things to be wrapped in quotes; if you use something like `subprocess` to execute `aws` directly (bypassing the shell), you don't need extra quotes.

Comment: @SuperStormer, are you saying to dump the output to a json file instead of stdout? I have to hand format some stuff because the data is not in the form it needs to be for uploading yet

Comment: @chepner, I'll try that some more, I was using a bash script since I have to run in an aws authenticated venv

Comment: There's also `boto`, which is a Python library for interacting  with AWS. (The command-line client is, I think, just a bunch of shell-convenient wrappers around `boto`.)

Comment: I ended up going with boto3, thanks for the advice! I wish there was a conclusion to this though since I'm sure it'd be useful to know

Answer (score 0):

Sample `pwds` dict data:

```
import json

pwds = {
    'id001': {
        'username': 'user001',
        'pswd': 'pwd123'
    },
    'id002': {
        'username': 'user002',
        'pswd': 'pwd123'
    }    
}
```

As suggested by SuperStormer, it's a better to use Python types (dict, list, etc) instead of building your own JSON.

```
secrets = [{id: f"{val['username']}, {val['pswd']}"} for id, val in pwds.items()]
json.dumps(secrets)
```

`'[{"id001": "user001, pwd123"}, {"id002": "user002, pwd123"}]'`

The JSON string should be usable within Jenkins script blocks.
Try experimenting with single quotes or `--secret-string file://secrets.json` as alternatives.